# linux kernel crash dump creation failure

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, coredump

I have a linux VPX on XEN. Which is not creating any core-dump when panic is occurred. 
Which part of the linux code contains crash dump creation program and how can I debug this thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check server's VMCore configuration. Kindly follow below steps

1./etc/kdump.conf – will have the below mentioned lines.

-----------------------------snip-----------------------------

```
ext4 UUID=6287df75-b1d9-466b-9d1d-e05e6d044b7a
path /var/crash/vmcore
```

-----------------------------snip-----------------------------

2./etc/fstab – will have the UUID and filesystem data.

-----------------------------snip-----------------------------

```
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Wed May 25 16:10:52 2011
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=117b7a8d-0a8b-4fc8-b82b-f3cfda2a02df /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=e696757d-0321-4922-8327-3937380d332a /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=6287df75-b1d9-466b-9d1d-e05e6d044b7a /data                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=d0dc1c92-efdc-454f-a337-dd1cbe24d93d /prd                    ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=c8420cde-a816-41b7-93dc-3084f3a7ce21 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
#/dev/dm-0                        /data1                                                                        ext4            defaults                    00
#/dev/mapper/mpathe                     /data1                                                                  ext4            defaults                    00
/dev/mapper/mpathgp1            /data2                                                                  ext4            noatime,data=writeback,errors=remount-ro                             0       0
LABEL=/DATA1                    /data1                                                            ext4          noatime,data=writeback,errors=remount-ro    00
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

-----------------------------snip-----------------------------

3.With the above configuration the VMCore will be generated in the /data/var/crash/vmcore path. 
Note: the VM core will be generated more than 10 GBs, hence configure the path where we have enough space)

Regards,
Jain

Comment: I don't have any file called /etc/kdump.conf on my XEN server.